# wordpress multisite plugin manager and login issue

Tags: wordpress

i have a blogging system in `wordpress`

1. i want to active some `plugins` in my network but users(the blogs
   owners) cant access to `plugin` setting in their dashboard, only can
   use theme
2. another thing that i want to do is that users can login to their
   `weblogs` via main site, not to going to their `weblogs` and do login

edit and solved:
the first problem solved via `admin menu editor` plugin and the second also solved via `Redirect Users to Primary Site` plugin than i think its not an official plugin for wordpress.

Comment: you should write your answer in answer box so that someone else could avail from it.

Comment: stackoverflow banned me from answering, please copy my answer to answer box and i will check as correct answer, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first problem solved via admin menu editor plugin and the second also solved via Redirect Users to Primary Site plugin than i think its not an official plugin for wordpress.